# Error in Using getGEO Command of GEOquery Package of R for Bioinfomatic

Tags: r, bioinformatics

Iam using 3.1.2 version of R with Windows 7 OS. 
I am facing a problem while using the package GEOquery for bioinformatics.

when i run the commands

```
library(Biobase)
library(GEOquery)
library(limma)
library(RCurl)
library(XML)

# load series and platform data from GEO

gset <- getGEO("GSE1739", GSEMatrix = TRUE)
```

I get the error

```
ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/series/GSE1nnn/GSE1739/matrix/
Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : 
  Failed to connect to ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov port 21: Timed out
```

However it works fine with

```
gset <- getGEO("GSE1739", GSEMatrix = FALSE)
```

Please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ask questions about Bioconductor packages on the [Bioconductor support site](https://support.bioconductor.org).

Comment: or ask http://www.biostars.org/

Comment: The error message means that R was unable to connect to the NCBI FTP server.  See if you can connect to the ftp site outside of R.

Answer (score 0):

The timeout error could be caused by a network issue. If you still get the same error, check  that you are able to access ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/series/GSE1nnn/GSE1739/matrix/ with a web browser. `GSEMatrix = TRUE` seems to work OK with [GEOquery](http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/GEOquery.html) version 2.32.

```r
#R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31) -- "Pumpkin Helmet"
#Copyright (C) 2014 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
#Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
> library(GEOquery)
> 
> # load series and platform data from GEO
> # test GSEMatrix = TRUE
> gset <- getGEO("GSE1739", GSEMatrix = TRUE)
ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/series/GSE1nnn/GSE1739/matrix/
Found 1 file(s)
GSE1739_series_matrix.txt.gz
trying URL 'ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/series/GSE1nnn/GSE1739/matrix/GSE1739_series_matrix.txt.gz'
using Synchronous WinInet calls
opened URL
downloaded 301 Kb

File stored at: 
C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp8SU6Se/GPL201.soft

> summary(gset)
                             Length Class         Mode
GSE1739_series_matrix.txt.gz 1      ExpressionSet S4  
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
#...
other attached packages:
[1] GEOquery_2.32.0     Biobase_2.26.0      BiocGenerics_0.12.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] bitops_1.0-6   RCurl_1.95-4.5 tools_3.1.2    XML_3.98-1.1  
>
```

Comment: Dear David, i tried but the problem still persists. It does not seem to be a network issue as it works fine by taking `GSEMatrix = FALSE`.